# c# recorrer txt de abajo hacia arriba

Tags: c#

Tengo que recorrer un archivo txt pero en sentido contrario al usual, normalmete seria algo asi:

```
 using (var origen = new StreamWriter(rutaOrigen + "x.txt", 
 true, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
 {
      while ((lineaOrigen = origen.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
             //lineaOrigen es la linea del txt
      }
 {
```

Pero en este caso necesito recorrerlo de abajo hacia arriba...

No puedo guardarlo en un array porque el txt es demasiado pesado

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: ¿No puedes guardarlo en un `char[]` ? ¿Cuanto pesa el txt?

Comment: Hola, puede ser complicado asi que yo primero me aseguraría de que es realmente demasiado pesado, cuantos gigas ocupa el fichero? Si son megas entonces no hay problema.

Comment: Por ahora pesa 1Gb pero va a seguir creciendo. Ya lo medio solucioné recorriendo el archivo y guardando en un Dictionary<String, int> un campo clave y la linea donde lo consigue, de esa forma encuentro la última coincidencia que es lo que quiero. Dejo la pregunta abierta a ver si a alguien se le ocurre algo mejor.

Comment: Me temo que no es posible (o, al menos es muy complicado). Los archivos en Widnows se leen de forma secuencial, o sea, de principio a fin. Puedes hacer lo que comentas que has hecho, ir leyendo linea a linea hasta que llegues al final y almacenar la ultima cadena leida. Asi podrías acceder a la ultima linea sin tener que almacenar todo en memoria

Comment: @LuisGutierrez ¿por qué necesita recorrer el archivo de abajo hacia arriba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando  la propiedad `Position` de `FileStream` puedes lograrlo y leyendo el archivo desde el final hasta el inicio solamente obteniendo parte por parte del archivo utilizando un `buffer`.

En el siguiente ejemplo, solamente carga en memoria 1KB de texto del archivo. Disminuyendo la posición de lectura del archivo hasta llegar a la posicion 0:

```
      const int chunkSize = 1024; // Indica la cantidad de texto a leer, en es caso 1KB
        using (var file = File.OpenRead("archivo.txt"))
        {

            // iniciamos la lectura en el ultimo 1KB del texto
            file.Position = file.Length - chunkSize;

            // restara la cantidad de recoridos en el archivo hasta
            // que file.Position llegue a 0 que seria el inicio del archivo
            int loopCount = 1;

            int bytesRead;
            var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
            while ((bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                loopCount++;

                 // aqui obtienes 1kb de texto almacenado en el buffer
                 // este seria el texto que procesarias
                 var texto = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

                 ProcesarTexto(texto);

                //si la posicion es 0(inicio del archivo), detenemos el while 
                if (file.Position >= 0)
                    break;

                // por cada loop editamos la posIcion a leer. Eso lo hacemos restando al tamaño total del archivo por
                // el chunkSize(cantidad de bytes a leer) menos el numero del recorrido
                var nuevaPosicion = file.Length - (chunkSize * loopCount);

                // Si la nueva posicion es menor a cero es porque ya este seria el penultimo loop.
                if (nuevaPosicion <= 0)
                {
                    // le asigmanos la posicion inicial del archivo
                    file.Position = 0;

                    // editamos el buffer para que solo lea el total restante de bytes
                    // y asi no incluya texto ya procesado
                    buffer = new byte[chunkSize - Math.Abs(nuevaPosicion)];

                }
                else
                {
                    file.Position = nuevaPosicion;
                }
            }
        }
```

Ten encuenta que esta solucion no toma en cuenta el encoding en que esta escrito el archivo.

Comment: Es importante la matización que haces al final. Este código funcionará si el archivo está en UTF8.

Comment: Parece funcionar bien, en mi caso el encoding es ANSI (Encoding.Default), tengo que hacer el resto del desarrollo para estar seguro pero hice algunas pruebas y funciona bien, Gracias!!!